# Access multidimensional array values in UITableView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Im trying to access these values from array storing float:

```
color_Array = @[@[@96.0f,@178.0f,@228.0f]];
```

i need to get the first value of the inner first array and i tried :

```
float *first = [color_Array objectAtIndex:[indexPath.row][0]];
```

Im just getting an error : `expected identifier`

Any suggestions ?

Comment: You are fetching an array from 0th index. So store resultant into an array named as "SubArray" again. From "SubArray" get float values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a breakdown of the data structure you've created:

```
NSArray *color_Array = @[@[@96.0f,@178.0f,@228.0f]];
NSArray *subArray = [color_Array objectAtIndex:0];
NSNumber *firstNumber = [subArray objectAtIndex:0];
float first = [firstNumber floatValue];
```

You can combine them as you like.  For example:

```
float f = [color_Array[0][0] floatValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve by this way

```
NSArray *color_Array = @[@[@96.0f,@178.0f,@228.0f]];
for (NSArray *rgbArray in color_Array) {
    NSLog(@"%@",rgbArray);
    float r = [rgbArray[0] floatValue];
    float g = [rgbArray[1] floatValue];
    float b = [rgbArray[2] floatValue];
    NSLog(@"r:%f,g:%f,b:%f",r,g,b);
}
```